# C++ / Xcode Sockets bind() Error

Tags: c++, xcode, sockets

When trying to process the return value (should be int) from sys/sockets.h bind(), Xcode fails to compile with the error

`Invalid operands to binary expression ('__bind' and 'int')`

It seems to be pulling the incorrect function definition for bind(), because when I choose "Jump to definition" from the contextual menu, it gives me three options: 2 definitions from functional.cpp, and 1 from sys/sockets.h.  I have sys/sockets included in my code, how to I force the compiler to use the correct definition?

Comment: Use `::bind`, or better yet, avoid `using` declarations like the plague.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `::bind` or get rid of the `using namespace std;`.

Comment: No problem, you might want to also read [Why is 'using namespace std;' considered a bad practice in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c).

Comment: Will do.  Just returning to C++ after 10 years away, so quite rusty.

Comment: This just fixed my build on my whole project :) thanks

Comment: Great Answer, Thank You